# Oracle function errors Error(1,16): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@"

Tags: oracle, function

Learning to create oracle user defined function and here is the code:

```
create or replace function testf(@a as int)
returns int is
begin
return
(@a+5)
end;
```

Why is this not working for me? Error:
Error(1,16): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:          current delete exists prior

Comment: That is not Oracle syntax. Oracle database?

Comment: yes oracle database

Comment: `@` is not a legal character in an identifier name in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Oracle, then follow its syntax.

```
SQL> create or replace function testf (par_a in int)
  2    return int
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return par_a + 5;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> select testf(100) result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
       105

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function testf(a in int)
return int authid definer is
begin
  return (a+5)
end testf;
/
```

1. Replace **@a** with **a**.
2. Replace **as** with **in**
3. Remove **s** from returns.
4. To avoid a warning, add **AUTHID DEFINER** just before **is**.
5. For readability, add **testf** after **end**.
6. If part of a script, add a **/** on the line below **end**;